# What's a bank memory?

Tags: virtual-memory

I've search on Google but still don't understand. I've read about it into arm book, but they don't define it.

Could you explain me what is it, where is it used, what's the point to have it and, if you can, its used into arm chips.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you say exactly what book you were reading and quote the relevant section? Does it say "bank memory" or "memory bank"? The latter is just another way of saying "memory".

Comment: This seems to be a hardware-related question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm reading "The Definitive Guide to Cortex M-3 M-4 Processors". For exemple : "Processors also have banked stacked pointers". Yes, maybe it's hardware question sorry.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It seems to be computer architecture, to me. I think it's on-topic.

Comment: Rather than providing additional information in the comments, please edit the question.  We want questions to stand on their own, so people don't need to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Also, I don't quite understand where you got to "bank memory" from "banked stack pointers".  Are you really asking what "banked stack pointers" means?  If not, perhaps you can clarify what you are asking, and look for a better example?

Comment: You might find helpful the first half of [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/102743/15426) to  the EE.SE question "What does banking mean when applied to registers?".

Answer (score 1):

Memory banks were an abstraction paired with a hardware implementation to extend the amount of memory normally available to a particular architecture.

For example, the PDP-8 had a "page" size of 128 12-bit words, and most instructions could only address memory on the same page as itself.  Other instructions could access the full memory complement of 2^12 (4K!) 12-bit words.  To go beyond 4K, special techniques could address memory outside the normal 4K. When implemented, the original 4K became (memory) bank 0 and other
memory banks numbers 1, 2 etc might exist.

The details varied, as computers worked their way up to today's standard
of 64 bit address space.